# Unable to import PyOpenCL on OSX (fail with exception)

Tags: python, macos, osx-mountain-lion, pyopencl

How do I get OpenCL to load in Python on Mac OSX?

Output

```
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:phoenix2-phoenix-2c83ee6 chris$ python opencl.py
[22:17:15] Python OpenCL Info v0.1
[22:17:15] Python Version: 2.7.2 64bit
[22:17:15] PyOpenCL Path: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyopencl-2012.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pyopencl
[22:17:15] Boost Python Version: Not Found
[22:17:15] Unable to load PyOpenCL! OpenCL not supported?
```

Source Code to test script.  (failing line is marked)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import time
from platform import architecture
from imp import find_module

timeformat = '%H:%M:%S'
def getTimestamp():
    return '[%s] ' % time.strftime(timeformat, time.localtime(time.time()))

def log(message):
    print getTimestamp() + str(message)

def getPythonVersion():
    info = sys.version_info
    return str(info[0]) + '.' + str(info[1]) + '.' + str(info[2])

def getPyOpenCLPath():
    try:
        file, pathname, descr = find_module('pyopencl')
    except:
        pathname = 'Not found'
    return str(pathname)

def getBoostVersion(input):
    try:
        contents = os.listdir(input)
    except:
        return 'Not Found'
    for i in range(len(contents)):
        if 'boost_python' in contents[i].lower():
            return contents[i]
    return 'Not Found'

path = getPyOpenCLPath()

#Display global information
log('Python OpenCL Info v0.1')
log('Python Version: ' + getPythonVersion() + ' ' + architecture()[0])
log('PyOpenCL Path: ' + path)
log('Boost Python Version: ' + getBoostVersion(path))

#Check for PyOpenCL not found
if path == 'Not Found':
    log('Exiting')
    sys.exit()

#Now we try to import PyOpenCL
# THIS IS WHERE THE FAILURE OCCURS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
try:
    import pyopencl
    import pyopencl.version
except:
    log('Unable to load PyOpenCL! OpenCL not supported?')
    sys.exit()

#Continue printing 
log('PyOpenCL Version: ' + pyopencl.VERSION_TEXT)

#get platfroms
try:
    platforms = pyopencl.get_platforms()
except:
    log('Stupid bug')

# If no platforms exist then no OpenCL supporting devices are present
if len(platforms) == 0:
    log('No OpenCL platforms found!')
    sys.exit()

log('Listing platforms and devices:')
count = 0

# Iterate through platforms
for i,p in enumerate(platforms):

    # Display platform
    log('')
    log('[cl:' + str(i) + '] ' + p.name.replace('\x00','').strip())

    # Get devices
    devices = platforms[i].get_devices()

    # Make sure we don't callback for a platform if no devices found
    if len(devices) > 0:
        # Iterate through devices
        for j,d in enumerate(devices):
            count += 1
            log('       [cl:' + str(i) + ':' + str(j) + '] ' + d.name.replace('\x00','').strip())


log('')
log('This program will exit in 300 seconds...')
time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Toggle the try, and post the effective exception. It could have some more interesting info (missing libraries, etc).

Comment: @pr0gg3d I'm new to Python ... do you mean remove the try?

Comment: As in http://pastebin.com/KvHzpcwG it should print the real exception.

Answer (score 1):

Does your hardware support OpenCL?  In some cases, I find it easier to debug similar issues by trying to run build and run example C programs.

Comment: I'm on a MacBook Pro Retna. I ran the BitMinter client and it says it can load OpenCL (whereas OpenCL won't work at all on older Macs).  I'm  quite new to this so any assistance would be appreciated.